# How would I open a Doorking gate and tell if it's open or not with an Arduino?

Tags: arduino, home-automation

I'm a software guy trying to get into hardware with home automation, and I have an Arduino and I was wondering how the electrical circuit would look/function.

The manual is here: https://www.doorking.com/sites/default/files/downloads/9150-065-X-4-14.pdf

The electrical schematics are on page 31.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: It depends what options you have and sensors installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the "gate tracker" interface on terminals 13 and 14 that looks like the best option, however it seems to speak a secret language there so you'll have to figure that out by observation

terminal 4 can be used to command the gate to open.

the dry contacts on terminals 15 and 16 can give you a 1 bit status according to the switch settings SW1(4,5) probably easier to use if it gives enough information..

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this out at see what I can do. So I would just connect terminal 4 to a pin on the Arduino and set it to high and low? The voltage is 3.3v on the Arduino so I'm not sure if that would match the gate.

Comment: I think you neecd a relay swithchng pin 4 and some other pin, probably ground. look at the wiring diagram for an exit button.